# What's the best way to display image thumbnails in one large block?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to display my images in a block with rows of five thumbnails each. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Currently I've got my container div set to 100% width. Would the solution be something along the lines of putting another div within the div that I would limit to a certain width or something?

```css
/* Site Wide CSS */

body {
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;   
    font-size: 16px;   
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;  
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: #555; 
}

p {
    text-align: center; 
}

/* Nav Bar Styles */

nav {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff; 
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: .5%;
    padding-bottom: .6%;

}

ul {
    padding-right: 2%;  
}

.navigation {
    display: inline;
    margin: .5%;

}

.logo {
    color:#000; 
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1%;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: .5%;  
    font-size: 79%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff; 
    clear: left;

}

/* Font Awesome */

i.fa {
    font-size: 2.3em;   
}

.container {
    padding-top: 2.5%; 
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;  
}


/* Styling for Photography and Design Pages */

.categories {
    font-size: 1.4em;   
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.imageGrid {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    text-align: center;

}

.images {
    width:9%;
    marign: 0;
    padding: 0;


}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sitewide.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photography.css">
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <h1 class="logo">B.Fun Photography &amp; Design</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<h2 class="categories">Landscapes</h2>
<div class="imageGrid">
    <a href="img/landscapes/br.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Blue Ridge Sunset"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Blue Ridge Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300y.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Duality"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Duality" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Methuselah"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Methuselah" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Old City Cemetary"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Old City Cemetary" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Mcafee's Knob"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Mcafee's Knob" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Appalachian Farmland"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Appalachian Farmland" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Blackwater Falls"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Blackwater Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Dark Hollows Falls"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Dark Hollows Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Elakala Falls"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Elakala Falls" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Humpback Rocks"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Humpback Rocks" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Lindy Point"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Lindy Point" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Lindy Point Sunset"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Lindy Point Sunset" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="The Overlook"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="The Overlook" class="images"></a>
    <a href="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Golyat"><img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w300" alt="Golyat s" class="images"></a>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>&#169; 2016 Brian Funderburke. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js">
    lightbox.option({
          'wrapAround': true,
          'alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices': true,
          'showImageNumberLabel': true,
        })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've put in a placeholder image to help you guys see what it looks like currently. I'd to have the thumbnails in rows of five. I've also been having difficulty getting rid of the margins between the thumbnails so help figuring that out would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ashus6sy/

The key thing is `font-size:0` on the containing element. White space takes a non-zero amount of space between each element, thus even with `width:20%` you wouldn't get exactly 5 objects because of these white spaces.

```
.imageGrid{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  font-size:0;
}
```

I also set `padding:0` and `margin:0` on everything.

`a` has `width:20%` whereas `img` has `width:100%` since the image widhth's 100% is relative to the `20%` of the `a`

Comment: The "white spaces" @Alexei is referring come from to places, spaces or returns in your HTML and from what is known as the descender heights of a letter like a lowercase **g** or a **j**. All inline elements will be treat _like_ an text character, meaning they will provide space for a any white space character like a space or return along with space for a  descender.

Comment: @Alexei Darmin Thanks for the help! Worked like a charm. What exactly do the > do in the css? I'm a bit new still and have never used them before.

Comment: No problem! the `>` in the realm of `CSS` refers to the direct descendants of the parent. Without them, the css would apply to any child no matter how many levels deep they are. I recommend reading this: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/